# Catching exceptions. Do you replace or wrap the using statement

Tags: c#, exception, using

The using statement doesn't capture exceptions. To catch exceptions you have two choices:

1) Unwrap the using and implement it manually:

```
void MyFunc()
{
    StreamReader myReader = null;

    try
    {
        myReader = new StreamReader(path);
        //use myReader
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //do something with exception
    }
    finally
    {
        if (myReader != null)
            myReader.Dispose();
    }
}
```

or 2) keep the using, and wrap it in another try catch block

```
void MyFunc()
{
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
             //use myReader
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //do something with exception
    }
}
```

To me the second one looks neater, especially when you having multiple using statements, because it describes the flow better, and removes the explicit declarations, null checks and Dispose() calls.

However, it feels wrong due to the extra try catch overhead which effectively redundant.

What's the standard practice?

Comment: How is the second way redundant?

Comment: Not particularly well-suited to SO on account of being poll'ish, but I prefer the latter inverted (the try/catch on the inside). It doesn't bother me at all that it may result in slightly more IL than manually doing the `Dispose` myself -- it's less work for me, which is the point of `using` to begin with.

Comment: @Tim: I guess I was thinking that the IL has got to set up two exception handling points. One for the outer try, and one for the implicit try within using.

Comment: @AlexanderGalkin The try-catch visible in the code is not: the `using` is (fsvo "is") as it does a [hidden] try-catch itself for the `Dispose`.

Comment: Have you *measured* the try/catch overhead? there's a myth that it is slow - and indeed, it *looks* slow inside an IDE, but that is **the IDE** slowing things down. Exceptions are actually alarmingly fast. Example: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/exceptions.html

Comment: @pst: Inverting it creates functionally different code, since it won't catch exceptions thrown by StreamReader's constructor.

Comment: @MarceloCantos Good call. I generally never catch those in-scope...

Comment: @pst: But what if an exception is thrown within the construction of myReader? It would not get caught if your handler is within the using block. EDIT: Marcelo beat me to it :)

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer Just not how I implement my code generally -- you and Marcelo are correct though, it does change the semantics. In either case, It Just Doesn't Matter (wrt using the `using` :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The overhead of exception handling constructions is just metadata. There is no runtime performance overhead if no exception gets thrown. Unlike some other runtimes entering/leaving an exception handling clause is free in .net. When an exception is thrown the runtime uses the metadata and the current instruction-pointer to figure out which handling clauses to execute.

I favor the second one. Releasing resources and handling exceptions are separate concepts, so it's only natural for them to be separate in code.

Comment: Do you have some documentation about exception handling not generating an overhead when there is no exception? A colleague of mine always claims this is case

Comment: +1 Bumping this link for [Exceptions and Performance](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/exceptions.html) from Marc: I'm not sure it's "free" (have to count the times an exception *is* thrown? ;-), but...

Answer (score 0):

You should try avoiding "try - catch" in methods, until and unless there is a very specific requirements for doing so.
Like for example checking the database connectivity before an applications starts.

Exception handling becomes a very costly affair in .Net application.

Nevertheless if you've got to then the 2nd option displayed is better.
Again this is subjective, to the very requirement of exception handling.

If it's for general error handling (like logging or sending error mails) then use the Global.asax.
Or at least limit it to the `Page_Error`  event.

Answer (score 0):

Another pattern to be aware of--especially useful in cases where an object being created will take ownership of another object (I normally code vb.net, so excuse any C# mistakes)

```
class MyDisposableClass
{
  SomeDisposableThing myThing;

  MyDisposableClass() // Constructor
  {
    bool ok = false;

    try
    {
      myThing = new SomeDisposableThing();
      ... do some other stuff
      ok = true;
    }
    finally
    {
      if (!ok)
      {
        zap(ref myThing);
      }
    }
  }
  static void zap<T>(ref T thing) where T:IDisposable,class
  {
    T oldValue = System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(thing, null);
    if (oldValue != null)
      oldValue.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Note that while one could catch and rethrow any exception which occurs during the constructor, if one is never going to do anything with an exception except rethrow it without change, it's better not to catch the exception than to catch and rethrow.